# How to keep three cards on the same line in bootstrap-5?

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I have a Django template for loop, which loops over the first three cards in the database. But they aren't staying on the same line. Only 2 of them are, but I want three cards on the same line.

```html
<div class="row">
    {% for jax in u_jaxes|slice:"0:3" %}
    <div class="col-5 m-2">
    <div id="card2" class="card">
        <div class="card-body"> 
            <a href="{% url 'edit_jax' jax.title %}">{{ jax.title|truncatechars:21 }}</a><br><br>
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/badge-html-5-128.png" alt="Badge, html, html5, achievement, award, reward, trophy"/ height="17" width="17"> HTML, CSS, JS
            <small><span style="float:right">
                {{ jax.date_created|timesince }} ago
            </span></small>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_jax' jax.title %}" class="stretched-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

**css**

```css
<style>
        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
        #plus {
            border: none;
            background: none;
            color: blue;
            border: 1px solid #E6E6FA;
            background: #E6E6FA;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        #plus:hover {
            border: none;
            background: none;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #E6E6FA;
            background: #1974D2;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transform: 4s;
        }
        #card {
            width: 214px;
        }
        #card2 {
            width: 309px;
            margin-left: -8px;
        }
        #card2 a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        #see {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #img {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            object-fit: cover;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
        .row {
            width: 730px;
        }
        #sp {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
```

Note, that there is a particular spacing between the cards. I want the spacing to be the same too, along with the three cards being on the same line.

and for the css, i think all you need to care about is the `card2` stuff, including hover and all. And i think the `row` too. That's it. You can ignore the rest. But just to make sure, you can check all css if you want.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can simply do it with the help of grids.

Just do:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-4">...</div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/470/353/1*_ed9L5YlfdKC-D_THYCdJQ@2x.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    
   <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/470/353/1*_ed9L5YlfdKC-D_THYCdJQ@2x.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    
   <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/470/353/1*_ed9L5YlfdKC-D_THYCdJQ@2x.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: hi, could you tell me how to do it according to my code? Like the one i gave in the description. Thanks!

Comment: Replace col-5 with col-4. Then it should work.

Comment: hi, i tried it, but all it did was _not_ space the two cards on the same line evenly, and the third card is **still** on a different line. IT's not working. Do you have any alternates? Also, i think it may be a problem with my css, do you want to see my css too?

Comment: You are using bootstrap then why should I look for css?

Comment: no, i mean just to put width and height for the bootstrap cards, i use some css. Do you want to see it? IT may have a problem. But your solution doesn't work. Any alternates?

Comment: You can show but bootstrap has a grid system and your cards will be automatically resize acoording to device. There is no need to set width.

Comment: oh ok. But do you have the solution to my problem of putting three cards on one line?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then above code is the solution.

Comment: But your solution isn't working. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Solution is absolutely right. Maybe you are implementing it wrong with your vanilla CSS. Share your css code other than bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, i included the css. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete this line in your Css

```css
.row {
    width: 730px;
 }
```

and replace `col-5` with `col-4`. Then it should work

Answer (score -1):

check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) out - about halfway down

Bootstrap rows use `display: flex` and will automatically wrap to the next line (if they run out of space) unless you use `flex-wrap: no-wrap` like

```
<div class='flex-nowrap'>With Inline BootStrap</div>
OR
myDivInCSS {
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
```

As far as the spacing between the items - I assume you need `justify-content: space-evenly` or `space-between` on the flex row.

[Check out the docs!](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)

Comment: hi, i don't really get where i need to put this code you gave. Could you add this according to my code, meaning copy and paste my code into your answer, and add the solution in it for my understanding. Thanks!